# Database Naming Convention Tool

Tags: database, naming, convention

So, like most places, reach a certain critical mass where you have so many databases, tables, columns that nothing is consistent like it should be.

Establishing a policy/data dictionary is one thing, but enforcing/measuring success is a different challenge.

Question:  With regards to enforcing/measuring success of column naming (just because of the exponentially larger number of objects compared to table/view/sproc/db/etc), are there any tools out there that support 'supplying' the accepted standard items and the non-accepted permutations?

I started writing JDBC getMetadata style code to pull the column names, then just do a simple check against a 'bad' column name repository to recommend what the good column name should be, but as always good to ask if something like this already exists (and/or problems you could run into).

If you post a tool that does a lot (i.e. your MDM, Sql tool, or other), please provide a specific example on how to manage convention name.

Example:  Instead of 'State', 'ST', 'State code', 'state_code', 'state cd', only use STATE_CD for a column name.

thanky